# Can't seem to ignore library in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm updating a project from VS2008 to VS2010 and I'm getting this error:

> uafxcwd.lib(afxwinappex.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual struct
>   CRuntimeClass * __thiscall CWinAppEx::GetRuntimeClass(void)const "
>   (?GetRuntimeClass@CWinAppEx@@UBEPAUCRuntimeClass@@XZ) already defined
>   in WinAppEx.obj

I've tried everything I can think of. uafxcwd.lib is in the "Additional Dependencies" and "Ignore Specific Default Libraries" settings in the Linker. For some reason it doesn't seem to ignore the uafxcwd.lib library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds obvious, but have you tried cleaning your solution and rebuilding it again?

Comment: Yeah. That usually solves these weird issues, but not this time.

Comment: Have you tried this, check the linking order:  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q148652

Comment: Yes, the ordering I have is the only one that doesn't cause hundreds of errors. Also, the WinAppEx.obj does not come from a library, so I can't order the uafxcwd.lib with it.

Comment: If you put this .lib in "Additional Dependencies" then it is not going to be ignored.  You are compiling source code with incompatible settings, make them all the same.

Comment: Incompatible settings? Could you please elaborate on what this might entail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. The issue is that uafxcwd.lib in VS2010 introduced a new class cwinappex. This was identically named to the class I had made, causing the conflict.

Who'd have thunk it?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem long time ago and I found a project that had proper setting and compiles without errors. I have also made some notes but I do not remember how (where) I got the solution.

Here it is:

You are using C runtime libraries in the MFC project and libraries are linked in the wrong order.
CRT and MFC libraries contain new, delete and DLLMain where CRT are using weak external link.
All functions in the MFC libraries have to be linked before CRT.

In order to achieve this, do the following:

In the project setting, link, input, go to the ignore libraries and add Libcmtd.lib. This will exclude Libcmtd.lib from the link process.

Since you need it, it has to be included. You can force it by adding library in the Additional Dependencies box. BUT add libraries in following order: uafxcw.lib LIBCMT.lib.

As yu can see, uafxcw.lib is **BEFORE** LIBCMT.lib. this should fix your problem.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. The conflict is not between those two libraries, but in between uafxcwd.lib and a generated obj file.